# VBScript - create button in the notepad window

Tags: vbscript

Using VBScript, I want to add an additional button to Notepad labeled “send” . The send button should be located near the help menu in the Notepad window

Please advise if it is possible to add a button inside Notepad. And if it possible then how can I create the button using VBScript?

Note - why I need to add the send button: The purpose of the send button is to send the file opened in Notepad to a remote Linux machine over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with VBScript. You could possibly manage to add the button, but you couldn't hook anything to respond to it being clicked.

You could probably hack something together using the native Win32 API, but it's more work to do that than it would be to write your own simple editor in any other language and use it instead of Notepad. (Notepad is simply a thin wrapper around a multiline edit control provided by the Windows API.)

Comment: can you give me example how to create simple editor with "send" button by VB script?

Comment: I said "write your own simple editor"; I didn't say "in VBScript". VBScript is a scripting language; I wouldn't try to do anything serious with it. It's designed for automating common tasks and things like that, not for writing full-blown applications. You can search for something that does this, but I don't have any examples because I wouldn't do anything like that myself.

Comment: If you are really, really, really stuck to VBScript, you can create a HTA file (standalone html application) with a multiline input field, a Send button a Save/Open option etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's Impossible via VBScript but with help of more serious languages like c# or c++ freely:
for example see project of my friend:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/automatingwindowsapps.aspx